# Possible to re-enter into an existed issued docker container which already down?

Tags: docker

**Background:**

I need to develop a Dockerfile.

But before that, I want to choose a base image, and start a container base on this base image.

After the container start, I would like to try install some packages & also modify some configures of my service. If manually done everything ok, finally I could move all these steps: package install & configure settings (which proved to work by manual try) to my Dockerfile.

**Problem:**

Sometimes, after I have tried a lots of correct steps, then make a wrong configure. What's the worse, I stop the container & start the container again to prove the start script is ok or not.

But unfortunately, the container already cannot be started because wrong app configure in container.

In fact, I want to try other configure in container, and then maybe everything will be ok, but I nolonger have the chance to enter into the container again. I don't want to resetup a new container, because I have already do many manual things in old container (Haven't move the correct steps to Dockerfile because I'm in development phase, I want to do it after I prove everything is ok)

**Next is the minimal example to show my case:**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine

ADD ./docker-entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod 777 ./docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

touch /tmp/app.log
tail -f /tmp/app.log
```

**What I will do with above:**

```
docker build --no-cache -t try .
docker run -idt --name me try
docker exec -it me /bin/sh
```

Change `docker-entrypoint.sh` to next:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit 0
touch /tmp/app.log
tail -f /tmp/app.log
```

Then:

```
docker stop me
docker start me # the container will not start
```

And now, I know `exit 0` maybe wrong command or wrong configure, I want to try again with other things, but no chance.

**Again, want to note**:

I do not want to resetup a container because I've already do many things in manual in old container, not just `exit 0`.

And, **`supervisord`** also not what I needed in my development lifecycle, I just want to make things simple. Something like change `entrypoint for an already existed container`(Seems just work for `docker run`)

Any suggestion for me to ease my development phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Basically, you now have a container that runs a script that exit immediately. Yet, you want to save it.

How about trying the followings:

1. Commit your container as another image.

   docker commit me me/snap:v001
2. Run bash using the image.

   docker run -it --name me2 me/snap:v001 bash
3. Fix your entrypoint code.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your Dockerfile.  Edit, run `docker build`, repeat.

There's nothing especially magical about a Dockerfile.  If you take your approach but decide to take detailed notes in a text file: I want to start `FROM` some base image, then `RUN` some command, `COPY` some files in, and `RUN` some other command: that's a Dockerfile.  It has the advantage of always starting from a clean environment, and always being reproducible.

For example, say you're trying to compile some package by hand, but don't quite have the configure options right.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential
WORKDIR /package
COPY some-package.tar.gz ./
RUN tar xzf some-package.tar.gz
WORKDIR /package/some-package
RUN ./config --wrong-option
RUN make
RUN make install
CMD ["some-command"]
```

Now you can run `docker build .` and it will run through this sequence of commands.  Perhaps when it reaches `RUN ./config` it will fail (because the script is actually named `./configure`).  You can edit the Dockerfile and re-run `docker build`, and Docker will start over where it failed before.  Similarly, when you discover that `--wrong-option` is wrong, you can change it and `docker build` will restart from the changed line.

If you need to do further debugging on a broken stage (maybe `--wrong-option` makes it through the configuration step but building fails) the `docker build` output includes an image ID for each layer, and you can `docker run --rm -it 0123456789ab sh` to get a shell on the partial image before the step that's having problems.

There are optimizations like combining `RUN` lines together and multi-stage builds that are useful, but you can save them for last.

`docker exec` isn't intended to be the primary way you interact with Docker.  You'll run into exactly the problems you're encountering: there's no persistent record of what you've done, it's not especially reproducible, and if the container ever gets deleted you'll lose all your work.

Comment: Yes, `docker exec` is not the primary way to interact with docker, but this way I can quickly know what I should put in `dockerfile` because my short-term memory could let me do it. And what I mean is runtime issue (things after CMD or Entrypoint), not the one in build (RUN or others)

Comment: Same answer: write a script, `COPY` it into your image, `docker build`, `docker run`, repeat.  I wouldn't rely on an interactive shell here.